# Is it possible to use DbContext code to access JSON data from a WebApi?

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-core, asp.net-core-webapi, dbcontext

I have an ASP.NET Core 2.1 web app that I created following the steps in the [Create Razor pages web app](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/tutorials/razor-pages/?view=aspnetcore-2.1) in the ASP.NET Core docs. Everything went as expected and I used the default localdb that was created when I scaffolded the Model. That part is fine.

What I need to do, however, is to try to use the same general code in a production environment where all CRUD functions are performed by calling WebApi methods, using JSON data that directly matches my Model objects.

For example, the Page that is created by scaffolding for the Create is this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnPostAsync()
{
    if (!ModelState.IsValid)
    {
        return Page();
    }

    _context.Registration.Add(Registration); // Here
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();       // Here

    return RedirectToPage("./Index");
}
```

and

```
public async Task OnGetAsync()
{
    Registration = await _context.Registration.ToListAsync(); // Here
}
```

Is it possible, or even feasible, to simply change every occurrence of _context operations, like the lines marked "//Here", to use calls to WebApi methods? Is there a better way to accomplish what I'm trying to do?

Comment: Sure, have you looked up calling rest api calls from C#?

Comment: Yes, of course. What I'm trying to do is keep as much of the generated code as possible, even the use of _context if I can somehow change it to use data read from a WebApi returned value, instead of connecting to, and reading from, an actual database.

Comment: So instead of adding data to a database, using a DBContext, you are looking for a convenient way to call a WebApi. If i truly understand what you are asking, the answer is not really, they are apples and oranges (or should i say, apples and bowling balls), they share just about no similarly. you are going to have to write WebRequests and you cant get out of it

Comment: I know I will still have to have the calls to the WebApi. What I was hoping to accomplish was to maintain as much of the _context related code as possible. Thank you for your help!

Comment: So, correct me if I'm wrong, but I could get around the requirements for two very different data environments by only calling the AddDbContext method in Startup when I'm running locally with an actual database (which causes the DbContext to be injected into the PageModel based classes), and NOT make the call to AddDbContext when I'm using calls to WebApi for my data (and use an empty ctor in the PageModels).Or, create my own extension to use with the ServiceCollection so my custom data context will be injected into the PageModels?

Comment: I would create a repository interface for accessing the data and inject that into your controller instead of the DbContext directly. You could then have two different implementations of the interface, one that uses DbContext and one that use HttpClient, and register the appropriate one in Startup based on the environment.

Answer (score 0):

You can only work with entity classes. However, you can convert JSON into an instance of one of your entity classes. For example:

```
using (var response = await _client.GetAsync("/foo/1"))
{
    var foo = await response.ReadAsAsync<Foo>();
    _context.Add(foo);
    await _context.SaveChangesAsync();
}
```

The `ReadAsAsync` method is syntactic sugar that simply reads the response as a string and then passes that on to JSON.NET to convert into the type specified. If you have just a JSON string, you can instead utilize:

```
var foo = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Foo>(jsonString);
```

That said, this is a code smell. If your API is *already* interacting with your entity classes, all the work should be done there. If you want to add a new entity, there should be an endpoint on your API for that. Likewise for all the other CRUD operations. Having two different apps working with your same context, and only in pieces at that, is a recipe for disaster.